# How is the von Neumann entropy of a state defined from its eigendecomposition?

Tags: information-theory, entropy

The definition of the von Neumann entropy of a mixed state says that it can be calculated as the Shannon entropy of coefficients of the decomposition of the state into a sum of projectors.

My question: Are we assuming this decomposition is a family of orthogonal states or can it be anything?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the projectors must be orthogonal and rank one. The coefficients are actually the eigenvalues of the density matrix, so  orthogonality follows from the spectral theorem. More precisely, if
$$
\rho=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_iP_i=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i|\psi_i\rangle\langle\psi_i|\tag1
$$
is an *eigendecomposition* of the mixed state $\rho$, then its von Neumann entropy is the Shannon entropy $H$ of the eigenvalues $\lambda_i$
$$
S(\rho)=H(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)=-\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\log\lambda_i.\tag2
$$
The spectral theorem guarantees that $\rho$ can be written as in $(1)$ and that $|\psi_i\rangle$ are an orthonormal basis.

---

Incidentally, the Shannon entropy of the coefficients of an expression of $\rho$ as a convex combination of *arbitrary* projectors is not a valid definition of anything. For example, the state $|0\rangle\langle 0|$ can be written as
$$
|0\rangle\langle 0|=\sum_{i=1}^mp_iP\tag3
$$
where $P=|0\rangle\langle 0|$ is a projector and $p_1,\dots,p_m$ is *any* valid probability distribution. Clearly, if we allow the set of (non-orthogonal) projectors $\{P,\dots,P\}$ then $S(|0\rangle\langle 0|)=H(p_0,\dots,p_n)$ would be equal to every non-negative real number.

Thus, if the projectors in $(1)$ were not orthogonal then the definition $(2)$ would make no sense.